# How can I store the result of this command as a variable in my bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm building a simple tool that will let me know if a site "siim.ml" resolves. If I run the command "ping siim.ml | grep "Name or service not known"" in the linux command line then it only returns text if the site does not resolve. Any working site returns nothing.

Using this I want to check if the result of that command is empty, and if it is I want to perform an action.

Problem is no matter what I do the variable is empty! And it still just prints the result to stdout instead of storing it.

I've already tried switching between `command` and $(command), and removed the pipe w/ the grep, but it has not worked

```sh
#!/bin/bash

result=$(ping siim.ml | grep "Name or service not known")

echo "Result var = " $result

if ["$result" = ""]
then
        #siim.ml resolved
        #/usr/local/bin/textMe/testSite.sh "siim.ml has resolved"
        echo "It would send the text"
fi
```

When I run the script it prints this:

```
ping: siim.ml: Name or service not known
Result var =
It would send the text
```

Comment: `if ["$result" = ""]` is not right.  When `result` is empty, that becomes `if [ = ]` which succeeds because `=` is not the empty string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or even slightly more terse, just check whether `ping` succeeds, e.g.

```
if ping -q -c 1 siim.ml &>/dev/null
then
    echo "It would send the text"
    ## set result or whatever else you need on success here
fi
```

This produces no output due to the redirection to `/dev/null` and succeeds only if a successful `ping` of `siim.ml` succeeds.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! I think I was getting the result of the ping confused with the output.

Comment: Yes, happens. Remember, you can always use the return of the command directly as the test in an `if ... then ... fi` rather than trying to save the output. Good luck with your scripting.

Answer (score 2):

It's almost certainly because that error is going to standard *error* rather than standard *output* (the latter which will be captured by `$()`).

You can combine standard error into the output stream as follows:

```
result=$(ping siim.ml 2>&1 | grep "Name or service not known")
```

In addition, you need spaces separating the `[` and `]` characters from the expression:

```
if [ "$result" = "" ]
```

Comment: when I make this chage the result becomes ```Result var =  ping: siim.ml: Name or service not known
./checkSiim.sh: line 8: [ping: siim.ml: Name or service not known: command not found```

Comment: So it assigns the var but then breaks line 8 which is the if statement?